# XCConfig not refreshing until Xcode is restarted

Tags: ios, xcode, xcconfig

I want to have a single target and several compilation schemes, and have some compiler definitions declared by a pre-action script of the schemes.

The pre-action script is generating a *comp.xcconfig* file which is #included by [Release|Debug]Config.xcconfig.

My generated *comp.xcconfig* holds this line:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) MY_TEST
```

My app include these lines:

```
#ifdef MY_TEST
    #error ye
#else
    #error oy
#endif
```

Compiling with the above configuration is resulting with error 'ye', as expected.

> If I then change *comp.xcconfig* to be:
>
> ```
> GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) MY_TEST1234
> ```
>
> I'm still getting 'ye'. But if I quit Xcode and restart it, I'm
>   getting the expected 'oy'.

**My Question:**

Is there a way to force Xcode to track xcconfig files for changes without the need to exit Xcode?

Comment: I'm having the same issue since Xcode 8.2.1 update. Please [submit a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) if you haven't yet.

Comment: Resolved in Xcode 8.3 beta:
"Changes to xcconfig files no longer require restarting Xcode to take effect. (29805284)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Xcode 8.3 beta release notes, this problem is fixed:

> • Changes to xcconfig files no longer require restarting Xcode to take
>   effect. (29805284)

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.3_beta/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8.3_beta.pdf